# C++ Array Values Not Changing

Tags: c++, arrays, sparkcore, fastled

I am working with FastLED on a Particle Photon in C++ and am trying to assign a new value to one of the elements of the pixel array.

Essentially, I have a array declared as such:

```
NSFastLED::CRGB leds[1];
```

I pass this into an "animation" class I've written in order to change the LED values:

```
void SomeClass::loop()
{
  // Get the pointer to the current animation from a vector
  Animation *currentAnim = animations.at(currentAnimation);
  currentAnim->animate(leds);

  ...
}
```

In the animation, I am trying to do something really simple-- set an element of that LED array to some value. For testing, even setting it to a static integer "0" would be fine.

```
void MyAnimation::animate(NSFastLED::CRGB *leds)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < numLeds; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(leds[i]); // "1"

    leds[i] = 0;

    Serial.print(leds[i]); // "1"
  }
}
```

The issue is, the array element is not being set at all. As you can see, this is even inside of the animation class that I am having the issue. I've also tried using `(leds*)[i] = 0`, but that doesn't have any effect either.

Why is it that the value is not being set in the array?

Comment: what is the implementation of `NSFastLED::CRGB::operator=(int)`?? Or is there a ctor `NSFastLED::CRGB(int)`?

Comment: https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/ccf12263ce06218302c7bdcb7879a6e90122266e/pixeltypes.h#L170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array data type is NSFastLED::CRGB, this holds RGB values, and can be assigned like below (from https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/wiki/Pixel-reference )

If you just want to store a number you could use int instead of NSFastLED::CRGB.

```
// The three color channel values can be referred to as "red", "green", and "blue"...
  leds[i].red   = 50;
  leds[i].green = 100;
  leds[i].blue  = 150;

  // ...or, using the shorter synonyms "r", "g", and "b"...
  leds[i].r = 50;
  leds[i].g = 100;
  leds[i].b = 150;


      // ...or as members of a three-element array:
      leds[i][0] = 50;  // red
      leds[i][1] = 100; // green
      leds[i][2] = 150; // blue
```

Comment: I should point out that even assigning a CRGB value doesn't work (either using a built in color in FastLED, such as CRGB::Red), and modifying the r/g/b values also seems to do nothing at all.

Comment: If you just use a declaration like int leds[1];

Comment: So if you set leds[0].r = 1 then print the value of leds[0].r it is not 1?

Comment: Do we know the value is not right, or the print is not working? Can you see a breakpoint + watch point to check if the value is actually changing in memory

Comment: What is value of numLeds

Comment: numLeds is simply 1, since there's only 1 element in the array. I don't have the ability to debug this properly because it's running on a Particle Photon, but I did add an if statement to check the value-- it seems to be the print that is faulty and displaying 0. The "if" fires when I check for the number I'm assigning.

Comment: The site has more examples like this:Serial.readBytes( (char*)(&leds[i]), 3);   https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/wiki/Controlling-leds

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Now the issue seems to be that the original array (the one in the loop method) isn't being changed... Not sure if I'm using arrays/pointers correctly to change the original array since I'm not a C++ dev.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93635/discussion-between-malcolm-mccaffery-and-andrew-m).